# How to save created flashcards to localStorage?

Tags: javascript

I am making a small project where you can make flashcards that populate a grid inside of a div that has a class of "grid-cards". At the very bottom of my Codepen Javascript code you can see I attempted to save all the created flashcards to localStorage so when the user refreshes the created flashcards will still be there.

```js
//Add Question button toggle and close button function
const addQuestionBtn = document.querySelector("#add-question")
const formContainer = document.querySelector(".hidden")
const closeBtn = document.querySelector("#close-btn")



addQuestionBtn.addEventListener("click", function addBtnToggle() {
    if (formContainer.className == "hidden") {
        formContainer.classList.remove("hidden")
        formContainer.classList.add("form-container")
    } else if (formContainer.className == "form-container") {
        formContainer.classList.remove("form-container")
        formContainer.classList.add("hidden")
    }
})

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function closeForm() {
    if (formContainer.className == "form-container") {
        formContainer.classList.remove("form-container")
        formContainer.classList.add("hidden")
    }
})

//Form event listener / Creating cards to populate grid
const questionInput = document.querySelector("#question-input")
const answerInput = document.querySelector("#answer-input")
const saveBtn = document.querySelector("#save-btn")
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid-cards")

form.addEventListener("submit", function sumbit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    //Creating elements
    let questionValue = questionInput.value
    let answerValue = answerInput.value
    let div = document.createElement("div")
    div.classList.add("card")
    let h3 = document.createElement("h3")
    h3.setAttribute("id", "question")
    showHideAnswer = document.createElement("a")
    showHideAnswer.setAttribute("href", "")
    showHideAnswer.innerHTML = "Show/Hide Answer"
    let p = document.createElement("p")
    p.classList.add("hidden")
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button")
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("id", "deleteBtn")

    //Appending created elements to div
    grid.appendChild(div)
    div.append(h3)
    div.append(showHideAnswer)
    div.append(p)
    div.append(deleteBtn)
    h3.innerHTML = questionValue
    p.innerHTML = answerValue
    deleteBtn.innerHTML = "Delete"

    //Show and hide answer
    showHideAnswer.addEventListener("click", function showAnswer(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (p.className == "hidden") {
            p.classList.remove("hidden")
            p.classList.add("answer")
        } else if (p.className == "answer") {
            p.classList.remove("answer")
            p.classList.add("hidden")
        }
    })

    //Delete a flashcard
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function deleted() {
        grid.removeChild(div)
    })


    //Local storage

    //Gathering all the inner HTML from my grid which the created flashcards sit in
    localStorage.setItem("innerContent", grid.innerHTML)
    const innerContent = localStorage.getItem("innerContent")
    //Attempting to populate the grid with the users created cards
    grid.innerHTML = inner
})
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1100px;
    width: 100%;
}

.header {
    padding: 25px 0;
}

#add-question {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.innerForm-container {
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    padding: 20px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

h2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#question-input {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
}

#answer-input {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
}

#save-btn {
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding: 10px 100px;
}

#close-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    padding: 15px 20px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

.grid-cards {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 350px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 200px);
    grid-column-gap: 25px;
    grid-row-gap: 25px;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.card {
    background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 22px;
}

p {
    margin-top: 15px;
}

a {
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: block;
}

#deleteBtn {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="inner-container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1>Flashcards</h1>
                <button id="add-question">Add Question</button>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden">
                <div class="innerForm-container">
                    <form action="">
                        <h2>Question</h2>
                        <textarea name="" id="question-input" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                        <h2>Answer</h2>
                        <textarea name="" id="answer-input" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                        <button id="save-btn">Save</button>
                        <button id="close-btn">X</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-cards">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to get the content from  and then trying to repopulate it again after refreshing the page so basically all of the users created flashcards will be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You are properly saving the content of the grid. However, you are just not loading it into the grid when the page is loaded.

To do so, just add:

```js
grid.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('innerContent')
```