# localStorage is saving but not displaying after refresh?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save the users created flashcards so that when you refresh they will still be there. The innerHTML of my grid is saving fine it seems but when I try to put my grid.innerHTML set to the saved data and refresh my page it goes back to showing no flashcards. Here is the Codepen: https://codepen.io/Chasehud26/pen/rNrBmzJ

```
//Add Question button toggle and close button function
const addQuestionBtn = document.querySelector("#add-question")
const formContainer = document.querySelector(".hidden")
const closeBtn = document.querySelector("#close-btn")


addQuestionBtn.addEventListener("click", function addBtnToggle() {
    if (formContainer.className == "hidden") {
        formContainer.classList.remove("hidden")
        formContainer.classList.add("form-container")
    } else if (formContainer.className == "form-container") {
        formContainer.classList.remove("form-container")
        formContainer.classList.add("hidden")
    }
})

closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function closeForm() {
    if (formContainer.className == "form-container") {
        formContainer.classList.remove("form-container")
        formContainer.classList.add("hidden")
    }
})

//Form event listener / Creating cards to populate grid
const questionInput = document.querySelector("#question-input")
const answerInput = document.querySelector("#answer-input")
const saveBtn = document.querySelector("#save-btn")
const form = document.querySelector("form")
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid-cards")

form.addEventListener("submit", function sumbit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    //Creating elements
    let questionValue = questionInput.value
    let answerValue = answerInput.value
    let div = document.createElement("div")
    div.classList.add("card")
    let h3 = document.createElement("h3")
    h3.setAttribute("id", "question")
    showHideAnswer = document.createElement("a")
    showHideAnswer.setAttribute("href", "")
    showHideAnswer.innerHTML = "Show/Hide Answer"
    let p = document.createElement("p")
    p.classList.add("hidden")
    let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button")
    deleteBtn.setAttribute("id", "deleteBtn")

    //Appending created elements to div
    grid.appendChild(div)
    div.append(h3)
    div.append(showHideAnswer)
    div.append(p)
    div.append(deleteBtn)
    h3.innerHTML = questionValue
    p.innerHTML = answerValue
    deleteBtn.innerHTML = "Delete"

    //Show and hide answer
    showHideAnswer.addEventListener("click", function showAnswer(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (p.className == "hidden") {
            p.classList.remove("hidden")
            p.classList.add("answer")
        } else if (p.className == "answer") {
            p.classList.remove("answer")
            p.classList.add("hidden")
        }
    })

    //Delete a flashcard
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", function deleted() {
        grid.removeChild(div)
    })

    //LOCAL STORAGE
    function storedCards() {
        localStorage.setItem("items", grid.innerHTML)
        inner = localStorage.getItem("items")
        grid.innerHTML = inner
    }
})
```

I have tried many different thongs but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You already asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74829439/how-to-save-created-flashcards-to-localstorage). What was wrong with the answer?

Comment: You're not calling storedCards anywhere in your code, and you're also setting the value before then reading it, which makes no sense

Comment: where is the function storedCards() called ? Refresh reloads the page, but toggling the 'Ask Question' button toggle the card and question and answer is retained.